# What is the shortcut for replace in CodePen?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, codepen

In [CodePen](http://codepen.io/), what is the keyboard shortcut for 'Find & Replace'?

The help screen lists <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but the "option" key is for Macs.

What is the Windows equivalent?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> has no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through experimentation, it appears to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

[image: Replace]
[image: With]

Comment: Damn.. I was sure to have tried this one... Thanks

Comment: Nope, that appears to format the text